# I'm getting an error when i have more than 3 indexed arg for an event

Tags: solidity, truffle, events, truffle-compile

I want to add all the arguments for my event to be indexed

```
event TokenPurchase(
  address indexed purchaser, 
  address indexed beneficiary,
  uint256 indexed value,
  uint256 indexed amount,
  uint256 indexed refund_amount
);
```

But  im getting this error when i compile

```
TypeError: More than 3 indexed arguments for event.
```

Am I really limited to three items indexed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#events):

> Up to three parameters can receive the attribute `indexed` which will cause the respective arguments to be searched for: It is possible to filter for specific values of indexed arguments in the user interface.

Comment: Only exception is for event declared as anonymous (so can't be filtered by name), which can accept up to 4 indexed parameters.( [See the Solidity compiler source code](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/78be93856b469ca45da87ad372427cf18752b042/libsolidity/analysis/TypeChecker.cpp#L607) )